# Random and inconsistent error with the DefaultConnection string for ApplicationDbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication, connection-string

I have a weird behaviour in my MVC Application. At some point, I started getting a weird `Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.` error at all pages.

I am saying it is random and inconsistent, because:

1. It started happening when no changes to any connection strings were made
2. I get the error on Firefox most of the time
3. At the same time it works in Chrome and IE

Now, the connection string in question is added by my publishing profile and it looks like that:

`<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="DefaultConnection_ConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43819739/how-to-track-what-adds-a-defaultconnection-connection-string-to-web-config-of)

When I remove this connection string, the error in Firefox changes to

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

(again, at the very same time it works in Chrome and IE).

By 'it works' I mean I can log in to the page using my domain credentials (it is supposed to use AD authentication) and navigate through pages etc.

My MVC application is only supposed to use EF directly for Audit trail logging (optionally, stored on a local db). 
For that, I have set up a separate DbContext class that points to a specific separate connection string - this all works fine.

The 'DefaultConnection' is used by ApplicationDbContext that is used by the boilerplate OWIN authentication code:

`public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)`

[image]

Business data access layer is separated into a different web API and I have proper DbContext and connection strings set up there (also working fine)
The authentication to my web app is also done in the separate web API. I pass the credentials in the HTTPS post to the API, validate them with PrincipalContext and return set of Claims back to the web application.

In there, I get an instance of IAuthenticationManager
`this.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication`

and do the sign in with my ClaimsIdentity instance

`this.AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = rememberMe }, identity);`

Now, there's two questions:

1. Seems I do not need the ApplicationDbContext and the bits that use it at all im my app? I mean these:

`app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);`

2. Why did it started throwing errors and why does it still work in other browsers??

Thanks a lot for suggestions!

==========================

**UPDATE**
Actually, now I am getting the same error in Chrome as well, which makes me think this must be related to how long its been since I have logged on to the page on that browser... Or something...

So, after clearing cookies, my page works again in a given browser. What... Why?

Comment: This sounds fishy. How many instances of your application are running?

Comment: @MarkC. Hey Mark, not sure I understand the question. The application is hosted on IIS, how do you count instances? What does an instance mean in terms of a web app?

Comment: Is this only running on one server?

Comment: @MarkC - yes, just one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, now I know.

The reason was the 'OnValidateIdentity' bit of code inside the boilerplate ConfigureAuth() method.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                },


            });
```

It was trying to invoke the identity validation after a specified interval (30 minutes). So, 30 minutes from the time I logged in, it tried to validate the identity and thus invoked the problematic DbContext.

The reason it 'sometimes worked' and why I called it random/inconsistent is that every now and then I would clear the cookies or try different browser, which did not contain my cookie that triggered the validation. And then, I would see it working, and working repeatedly for quite some time